# Customizing XenServer partitions

Tags: linux, partitioning, installer, xen, xenserver

I wanted to install XenServer onto a hard disk with existing data on it, by customizing the partitioning and LVM volumes, but I found that the Anaconda installer does not seem to provide any options for doing this.  Most Linux distributions will have a disk druid to allow custom partitioning, but the XenServer installer simply wants to wipe /dev/sda!  Is it really impossible to customize the partitioning of XenServer whatsoever, and is it really required to install on the entire /dev/sda disk?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Unforunately it appears Xen can only be created in an empty LVM http://www.virtualizor.com/wiki/Install_XenServer